# Setting an icon to an element that will be inserted on an event

Tags: javascript

Got this page, https://jsfiddle.net/twpn01Lz/. It's a book library.

I'm trying to find a method to add a tick icon or X icon whenever someone selects a radio button.

At the moment, I can get the value of the radio button and work with it in JS but I don't know how to instead use the the icon for the value. I was looking for a method to replace it in JS but couldn't find one and also I was looking for a method to change it directly in HTML but no luck.

```js
function addBookToList(book) {
 const list = document.querySelector('#book-list');
 const row = document.createElement('tr');

 row.innerHTML = `
      <td>${book.name}</td>
      <td>${book.author}</td>
      <td>${book.pages}</td>
      <td>${book.read}</td>
      <td>
        <a href = '#' class='delete'> 
          <i class="fas fa-trash-alt delete">
          </I>
        </a>
      </td>
    `
 list.appendChild(row);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/yx4k6thw/

```
let read = document.querySelector('#radio1').checked ? "✔":"";
```

or perhaps

```
let readIt = document.querySelector('#radio1').checked;
let read = `<i class="fas fa-${readIt?"check":"times"}"></i>`;
```

Comment: Yes and No. Yes because it solves my problem but also, what if you would want to actually add an icon with each even instead of a symbol?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to style your radio Buttons? Or where do you want the X or Tick to appear?

If you want to style the Buttons check this out.

[Styling checkboxes and radio buttons using CSS](http://code.iamkate.com/html-and-css/styling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.